# TypeError: compile is not a function

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

How do I handle the error:

**TypeError: compile is not a function

     template = compile(script.html());**

in ember-1.0.0-rc.1.js?

The included frameworks are:

jquery-1.9.1.js

handlebars.1.0.0-rc.3.js

ember-1.0.0-rc.1.js

Comment: No. The bold text is 1:1 copied from the firebug output. But I think you are right, executed is Handlebars.compile(...). At the moment, I try to follow what James suggested. Ember.Handlebars.compile(...). Unfortunately, up to now without success.

Answer (score 3):

Ember only *requires* the Handlebars runtime (available as `handlebars.runtime.js` from http://handlebarsjs.com). If you want to do template compilation in the browser (as opposed to precompiling all templates and shipping the resulting JavaScript to the browser), you will need to include the full Handlebars on the page and change `compile` to `Ember.Handlebars.compile`. (`Ember.Handlebars.compile` wraps `Handlebars.compile` in some Ember-specific magic.)

For example,

```
<script src="/assets/jquery-1.9.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.3.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/ember-1.0.0-rc.1.js"></script>
```

and

```
MyView = Ember.View.extend({
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("{{foo}} {{bar}}"),
});
```

Comment: After I did what you proposed, similar error context. "TypeError: Ember.Handlebars.compile is not a function". Could you please suggest a common tutorial, to get familiar with the latest versions and how to cope this problem? ^Thx~

Comment: `Ember.Handlebars.compile` gets defined if and only if `Handlebars.compile` is defined. That's defined if you have the full Handlebars (not just the runtime). Are you *sure* you have the right Handlebars version?

Comment: ^Thx~ James, that's it. Unfortunately I mixed up during the copy process. The runtime source was in the full one. Why, I don't know. I checked that several times in advance.